# AWS: How to find the difference between 2 AMIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, filesystems, amazon-ebs, ec2-ami

I have an AMI that is already created from the base image ubuntu 18.04. There were some changes made to the base AMI like changing the filesystem type and also copying some files. Now the changes have not been tracked. I'm planning to build a new AMI for the same purpose using ubuntu 22.04 as the base image. I want to know what all changes were made in the first AMI. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: No such functionality is provided. You would need to compare the contents of the disk to the base image using some sort of Linux utilities.

Comment: Any guidance on those Linux utilities would be more helpful @JohnRotenstein

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for asking Programming Q&A. You might receive a better response at: https://serverfault.com/